# How come file_get_contents with google api if I read remote access was deprecated

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

The following server side is working perfectly for me (php):

`$json_result = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$val}&sensor=false&region=us");`

I was reading and figured there is a 2500 limit, so it's best to run this from client side.
At the same place I read that in order to use client side, I can not simply use jquery $.get() because google will not allow cross server scripting. Also, I am requested to use an apikey, and the limit is 25,000.

What am I not getting ?...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are geocoding the client side you should use the Javascript API.

If you use the V3 Javascript API you can use `google.maps.Geocoder` to request Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding, the documentation with examples is available [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html).  These limits are enforced per user so you won't be limited to 2.5K queries from your backend.